# Non-persisted field in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Can I define a field in mongoid, but not persist it?
I need to_json to include the field, and using attr_accessor and after_initialize to calculate the value does not include it in the to_json result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by manipuating the JSON array itself, keeping most of the to_json power.

```
raw((c.to_json).insert(-2, ",\"url\":#{c.image_url.to_json}"))
```